# Show that an element of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has order $1,2,3,4,6$ or $\infty$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that an element of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has order $1,2,3,4,6$ or $\infty$.

My idea: $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})=\{A|A_{2 \times 2}$ & $det(A)\neq0\}$.

Let $A\in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and order of $A$ is $n\geq 2$.

$A^n=I$, the characteristic polynomial is $x^n-1=0$.

$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+......+x+1)=0$.

I know that the cyclotomic polynomial is an irreducible monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $\phi(n)$.

I confused how do I conclude that $n=2,3,4,6$ or $\infty$? Can anyone suggest me some hint?

Comment: Hint: the minimal polynomial of $A$ has degree at most $2$. (As a small correction, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is not (necessarily) $X^{n}-1$, but $A$ is indeed a root of $X^{n}-1$.)

Comment: I think a better notation than “$\{A|A_{2\times2}$ & $det(A)\neq0\}$” is $\{A\in\Bbb Z^{2\times2}:\det A\neq0\}$ personally.

Comment: As a small remark: $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ consists of the integer matrices invertible *over $\mathbb{Z}$*. So not all matrices with non-zero determinant, but those with unit determinant, i.e. $\det A = \pm 1$. Of course, any  integer matrix with finite order and non-zero determinant has determinant $\pm 1$, so this has no impact on your question or its answers :)

Answer (score 11):

Let $A\in GL_2(\mathbb Z)$.
Suppose $\ \exists n \in \mathbb N^* \ :\ A^n =I_2$
Then, $A$ is diagonalizable.
Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ its eigenvalues.
We have:
$\ \lambda_1^n=1\ $ , $\ \lambda_2=\overline{\lambda_1}\ $.

So, $\ \exists \theta \in \mathbb R \ : \ \lambda_1=e^{i\theta} \ \text{ and } \ \lambda_2=e^{-i\theta}$
Then $\ 2\cos\theta =\operatorname{tr}(A) \ $ is in $\mathbb Z$.

Therefore, we have 5 possibilities:
$\cos\theta = -1\ $ :  $\ A^2=I_2$
$\cos\theta = -\dfrac{1}{2}\ $ :  $\ A^3=I_2$
$\cos\theta = 0\ $ :  $\ A^4=I_2$
$\cos\theta = \dfrac{1}{2}\ $ :  $\ A^6=I_2$
$\cos\theta = 1\ $ :  $\ A^1=I_2$

Comment: +1, your proof is much easier than mine!

Comment: This answer requires only $A\in GL_2(\Bbb R)$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $A \in GL_2(\mathbb Z)$. In particular, $A$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial, which is a *quadratic* polynomial with *integer* coefficients, because $A$ is of dimension $2 \times 2$ and all its entries are integers.

Now, suppose that $A$ satisfies $A^n = I$ for some $I$, and for no smaller $n$ is that true. It follows that $x^n-1$ and the characteristic polynomial of $A$ share a common factor, but this is not true for any $m < n$.

Now, when can this happen? We have the celebrated formula $x^n-1 = \prod_{d | n} \Phi_d(x)$, where $\Phi_d$ is the $d$th cyclotomic polynomial. Furthermore, since each cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible, it follows that this is the unique breakdown into irreducibles of $x^n-1$.

Therefore, if the characteristic polynomial of $A$ shares a common factor with $x^n-1$, it is one of these polynomials. However, we know something more : the degree of $\Phi_d(x)$ is $\phi(d)$, the Euler totient function of $d$. In particular, only for $n=1,2,3,4,6$ is $\phi(n) \leq 2$, so only for these values can $\Phi_d(x)$ divide the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Can you finish from here?